# Azure Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics Extension

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-machine

Trying to configure the BootDiagnostics on a VM on a storage account in a resource group different from the VMs. To the best of my knowledge this can only be done by installing the VmDiagnosticsExtension. I'm executing the following:

```
Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName $RgName -VMName $VmName `
                                  -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath 'D:\DiagnosticsConfig.xml' `
                                  -StorageAccountEndpoint '/subscriptions/ff26f7/resourceGroups/rgroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/amsdiag01'`
                                  -StorageAccountName 'amsdiag01' `
                                  -StorageAccountKey 'key''>
```

I get this error message:

> ErrorMessage: Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics'
>   has reported failure for VM Extension
>   'Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings' with terminal error code
>   '1009' and error message: 'Enable failed for plugin (name:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics,  version 1.6.3.0) with
>   exception Command
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.6.3.0\DiagnosticsPluginLauncher.exe
>   of Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics has exited with Exit
>   code: -106'

No further information available in `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\WaAppAgent.log` on server. In the portal under 'Diagnostics' I can see the correct configuration. But the extension is in a '(unavailable)' state. Container in storage account is not created. Also, can't reboot the server due to the extension. I can remove and re-add the extension using PowerShell, but always same result. When performing a `Get-AzureRmVMExtension` I see the following 'Public Settings' entry:

> PublicSettings     : {
>                          "storageAccount": "amsdiag01",
>                          "xmlCfg": "PFdhZENmZz4NCiAgICAgIDxEaWFnbm9zdGljTW9uaXRvckNvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb24gb3ZlcmFsbFF1b3RhSW5NQj0iNDA5NiI+DQogICAgICAgIDxQZXJmb3JtYW5jZUNvdW50ZXJzIHNjaGVkdWxlZFRyYW5zZmVyUGVyaW9kPSJQVDFNIj4NCsKgwqDCoMKgwqAgICAgIDxQZXJmb3JtYW5jZUNvdW50ZXJDb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIGNvdW>                      eU5hbWU9IkNQVSBwcml2aWxlZ2VkIHRpbWUiIGxvY2FsZT0i

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen not to use extensions but instead using the following:

```
$RgName = 'RG1'
$VmName = 'VM01'
$Vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RgName -Name $VmName
$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -Enable -VM $Vm -ResourceGroupName $RgName -StorageAccountName diagss01
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RgName -VM $Vm
```